# Reference trouble

Tags: java, reference, parameter-passing

I am having trouble with the following code. Let me run through what the code is doing or meant to be doing. The `createZoo` method does the following:

1. It creates an array of `Cage` objects
2. To each index of this array a mating pair object is added that consists of two animal objects
3. `newZoo.add(cage[i])` - this passes the cage object to an add method in the `Zoo` class. It is added to a list in the `Zoo` class.

The problem then arises when I access this list in the `Zoo` class to retrieve the cage object. The cage object retrieved is the incorrect one. Sorry for the vagueness here but I think the problem lies in point 3 above when I pass the argument `cage[i]` to be added to the `List<Cage>` cage in the `Zoo` class. Should I be passing an index instead?

Thanks.

```
 class algo{

    private int counter = 15;
    private Zoo newZoo = new Zoo();


    public void createZoo() {

        Cage[] cage = new Cage[counter];

        //initialize cage array with cage objects
        initializeCageArray(cage);

        while(counter>0) //outer while loop
        for(int i =0; i<counter; i++)
        {


            for(int x = 0,y = end of array;x<somecounter; x++, y--)
            {
                Animal animala = Animal.get(x)
                Animal animalb = Animal.get(y);


                cage[i].add(new MatingPair(animala, animalb));


            }

            //adds cage object to list container in zoo class
            //Am I passing the wrong thing here - maybe I need to pass an index?
             newZoo.add(cage[i]);        

            --counter;

        }




    }
```

Comment: What is `y = end of array`? Is this your actual code?

Comment: No just pseudo code in loop

Comment: My main question is this: If I pass an object referenced by some index in an array such as cage[i]  to a method that adds this to a list of cage objects, should the list be able to reference this correctly? Or does the list need to be sent some form of index to be able to reference it correctly?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with adding `cage[i]` to a List.  That will pass a reference to the _ith_ element of your array.

Comment: You never pass objects -- you always pass references.  Specifying `cage[i]` as a parameter will pass the reference stored in the ith entry of the `cage` array.  Programmers are often "loose" in how they describe things, but it's important to learn to speak precisely when you're first learning.

Comment: Could you provide a more complete example and describe the problem in more detail? Also the definition of `initializeCageArray` is missing. The problem could well be there, for example assigning all array elements to the same cage.

Comment: Thanks all..I found the problem lay else where with a static modifier I had left in a class by mistake which meant one of the containers was constantly getting over written in error. However, it is good to cement the point made by @HotLicks above that you are always passing references and not objects. I had lost sight of this when I was trying to find my bug..

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly alright to pass the ***REFERENCE*** of `Cage` to the `Zoo` and it is better than passing the index to the `cages[]`.

Think now if `Zoo` class wants to do something with the `Cage` objects (supposedly open all cages!), then how would they access the objects of `Cage` using just the `index`. You will somehow also give access of whole array of `cages[]` to the `Zoo`.

So its much better if you directly passed the reference of `Cage`, as for **manipulating** the cage in anyway you will require the REFERENCE to it.

Hope it makes sense.